# An exercise about probabilities and residue classes

Tags: probability, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I do not know how to start with the following exercise:

> Fix $x \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and randomly (u.i.d.) chosse $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_q \in \mathbb{Z}_n$. Show that when $q$ is chosen as $q = \lfloor \sqrt{2n} \rfloor$ the probability $p$ that there exists $i$ and $j$ such that $r_i = x + r_j \bmod n$ is at least $p = 0.6$.

Could you give me a hint on how to start with this exercise?

Comment: Looks a lot like the Birthday paradox.

Comment: If I understand correctly, except when $x=0 \bmod n$, the probability of a "failure" at the $k$th step is $(n-2k)/n$; when $x=0 \bmod n$ it is instead $(n-k)/n$. So the probability of $q$ failures is some kind of truncated factorial divided by $n^q$. Thus the math is indeed quite similar to the birthday paradox (it is exactly the same when $x=0$).

Comment: @Ian: I understand how you get $(n-k)/n$ for $x = 0 \bmod n$, but how do you get $(n-2k)/n$ for the other cases?

Comment: Actually I'm mistaken, because there are two types of failure in the case $x \neq 0$: you can hit a point that you've hit already or not. Every time you hit a *new* point say $y$, you reduce the number of points permitted for a subsequent failure by $2$ (namely, $y-x$ and $y+x$, interpreted mod n). So the situation is a bit worse, from the estimation point of view, than I made it sound.

Comment: So if I understand correctly in case that $x \ne 0$ the chance for failure at the $k-$th step is $(n-3k)/n$  ?

Comment: No, it is more complicated because it depends on how many states you have hit thus far. The first step will fail with probability 1, the second step will fail with probability $(n-2)/n$, but the third step may fail with two different probabilities conditioned on how exactly the second step failed (did you hit the first value or a new value?)

Comment: It's even more complicated still because the new probability of failure depends on which point you hit. For example, consider $n$ very large, $x=1$, $r_1=1$, then compare $r_2=3$ vs. $r_2=4$.

Comment: But would it be an option to bound the probability of failure by $(n-3k)/n$ ?

Comment: No, because actually you can fail for an arbitrarily long time with positive probability by just hitting the same value over and over.