# Finding a probabalistic algorithm for the discrete logarithm problem

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, discrete-logarithms

I am working on the following exercise:

> $1)$ Fix $x \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and randomly (u.i.d.) chosse $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_q \in \mathbb{Z}_n$. Show that when $q$ is chosen as $q = \lfloor \sqrt{2n} \rfloor$ the probability $p$ that there exists $i$ and $j$ such that $r_i = x + r_j \bmod n$ is at least $p = 0.6$.
>
> $2)$ Let $p$ be a prime and $g \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}$ be a primitive root of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}$. Show that one can find in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}$ the discrete logarithm of $X$ to base $g$, if one can find $r$ and $s$ with 
>   $$g^r = Xg^s \bmod p$$
>
> Use this and part $1)$ to find an algorithm that solves in $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n}) $ steps the discrete logarithm probelm with high probability.

Let us assume that $1)$ is true.

The first claim of $2)$ should follow by observing:

$$g^r \cdot g^{-s} =  g^{r-s} = X \bmod p$$

But I do not know how to formulate the sought algorithm. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Why is the fact that you've done 1) not reflected in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825287/an-exercise-about-probabilities-and-residue-classes)?

Comment: @joriki: I am sorry, I expressed myself in the wrong way; I am not a native speaker. My teacher sent out an email saying we may also assume that $1)$ holds. I will edit my question.